# Whonix 14.0.0.7.4 KVM Workstation Screen Scaling

Tags: whonix

Unlike with Whonix 13, I find it quite difficult to run Whonix 14 under Debian stretch via KVM. Scaling the screen to full screen does work sometimes but sometimes it does not.

The first indicator is an error window indicating "KdeSudo: No command arguments supplied! Usage: kdesudo ...". Then, the host mouse if often (but not always) not connected to the guest screen. When the guest screen is operational, picking a higher screen resolution does not seem to be reboot persistent. Finally, I often get the error "drm:qxl_enc:commit [qxl] ERROR head number too large or missing monitors config" after restarting the Workstation which did scale once before.

Can anyone please be so kind to point me to a suitable next step?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's an upstream bug with the way KDE interacts with libvirt. Please feel free to chime in this bug ticket:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=356864

Other users discussing this on our forums:
https://forums.whonix.org/t/whonix-14-fresh-install-under-kvm-segmentation-fault-with-kscreen/5601/6